# React-native: How to implement caching for image in tvOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tvos, apple-tv

React-native: How to implement caching for image in tvOS ?

I want to implement caching for image that I download on internet, how to do that with apple tv ? I have tried many library, but anyone are compatible with the apple tv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React Native FS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) is now compatible with tvOS [see](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/pull/291). So now you can use any library that use it !

For exemple with [react-native-cacheable-image](https://github.com/jayesbe/react-native-cacheable-image) :

You need to install and link [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#usage-ios), just type:

```
npm install react-native-fs --save # install react-native-fs
react-native link react-native-fs #link native module
```

Now you can install [react-native-cacheable-image](https://github.com/jayesbe/react-native-cacheable-image#installation):

```
npm i react-native-cacheable-image --save
```

Import this library like this:

```
import CacheableImage from 'react-native-cacheable-image'
```

And now you can create an image like this with [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

```
 <CacheableImage
            style={{height:20}}
            source={{uri: "http://www.foobar.com/defaultImage.jpeg"}}
        >
```

There some specification in terms of your device just see the documentation of [react-native-cacheable-image](https://github.com/jayesbe/react-native-cacheable-image)

I hope my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do the caching by hand using [`AsyncStorage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html). You add objects that must be cached to the store using `AsyncStorage.setItem`, and get objects back using `AsyncStorage.getItem`. Both these functions will return promises.

```
// cache item
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyAppCache:myKey', myItem);
} catch {
  //couldn't cache item, handle it
}
```

```
// retrieve item from cache
try {
  const myItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyAppCache:myKey');
} catch {
  //didn't find item in cache, download from the internet
}
```

If this seems too low-level, there are some pretty good wrappers around `AsyncStorage` such as [react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage), which offer some goodies such as setting expiration dates on cached items, query batching and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) 

How i can give my image from uri to  AsyncStorage.setItem ?

Comment: And how I can pass my image on local to Image component ?

Comment: You can get your image as a base64 string. You can save base64 strings to AsyncStorage by simply doing `AsyncStorage.setItem(key, base64)`, and the React Native `Image` component supports displaying images directly from base64 strings by setting the `uri` property to the base64 string.

Comment: Thank you :) And how I can get base64 from my image ? Because some react library that do this, are not compatible with tvOS

Comment: It's better to send the image as base64 on the server side. But if you need to convert it on the client,  you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-to-base64).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I didn't succeed with this library it was not compatible with tvOS